# Spring Cloud - Feign - Failed to instantiate [feign.Retryer]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign

My project when running in Eclipse works correctly, however when I publish to Tomcat and start the services, only the gateway service returns the following error:

```
 
2018-09-20 16:07:56.734  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-38] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@717be834: startup date [Thu Sep 20 16:07:56 BRT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-20 16:07:56.856  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-38] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: file:/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9.0/webapps/config-data//server-config-gateway.yml
2018-09-20 16:07:56.857  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-38] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: file:/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9.0/webapps/config-data//application.yml
2018-09-20 16:07:56.857  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-38] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@717be834: startup date [Thu Sep 20 16:07:56 BRT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-20 16:07:56.917  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=server-config, profiles=[gateway], label=default, version=null, state=null
2018-09-20 16:07:56.917  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource [name='file:/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9.0/webapps/config-data//server-config-gateway.yml'], MapPropertySource [name='file:/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9.0/webapps/config-data//application.yml']]]
2018-09-20 16:07:56.926  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] c.d.m.ServerGatewayApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-09-20 16:07:56.933  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@66eea7e7: startup date [Thu Sep 20 16:07:56 BRT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1ed3d288
2018-09-20 16:08:00.471  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2018-09-20 16:08:00.645  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'managementServletContext' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]]
2018-09-20 16:08:01.776  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=636ce7a5-959f-3583-81f4-c242391e4274
2018-09-20 16:08:01.870  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-09-20 16:08:01.947  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'com.diogoaltoe.microservices.client.CustomerClient' of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-20 16:08:01.950  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'com.diogoaltoe.microservices.client.ProductClient' of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-20 16:08:02.304  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2f14c0a6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-20 16:08:02.832  INFO 10776 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2018-09-20 16:08:03.014  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'resourceServerProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-20 16:08:03.077  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsInterceptorConfiguration$MetricsRestTemplateConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsInterceptorConfiguration$MetricsRestTemplateConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$614166e7] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-20 16:08:03.172  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4b2ec3a3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-20 16:08:03.206  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6273 ms
2018-09-20 16:08:05.679  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'corsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-20 16:08:05.679  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-20 16:08:05.679  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-20 16:08:05.679  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-20 16:08:05.680  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-20 16:08:05.680  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-20 16:08:05.680  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-20 16:08:05.683  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-09-20 16:08:05.684  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-20 16:08:05.684  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-20 16:08:05.684  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'zuulServlet' to [/zuul/*]
2018-09-20 16:08:05.685  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-09-20 16:08:08.475  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-09-20 16:08:08.523  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-09-20 16:08:08.771  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2018-09-20 16:08:08.774  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-09-20 16:08:08.778  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2018-09-20 16:08:08.945  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-09-20 16:08:09.373  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2018-09-20 16:08:09.420  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2018-09-20 16:08:09.423  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@1a5b78cf
2018-09-20 16:08:10.665  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-09-20 16:08:10.803  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@64b8b66: startup date [Thu Sep 20 16:08:10 BRT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@66eea7e7
2018-09-20 16:08:10.854  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-09-20 16:08:11.028  WARN 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feignRetryer' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [feign.Retryer]: Factory method 'feignRetryer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NEVER_RETRY
2018-09-20 16:08:11.029  WARN 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.diogoaltoe.microservices.client.CustomerClient': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feignRetryer' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [feign.Retryer]: Factory method 'feignRetryer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NEVER_RETRY
2018-09-20 16:08:11.029  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-09-20 16:08:11.081  INFO 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-20 16:08:11.115 ERROR 10776 --- [io-8081-exec-35] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.diogoaltoe.microservices.client.CustomerClient': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feignRetryer' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [feign.Retryer]: Factory method 'feignRetryer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NEVER_RETRY
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5098) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1395) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:698) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:223) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.diogoaltoe.microservices.client.CustomerClient': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feignRetryer' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [feign.Retryer]: Factory method 'feignRetryer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NEVER_RETRY
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1634) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1316) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feignRetryer' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [feign.Retryer]: Factory method 'feignRetryer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NEVER_RETRY
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.createContext(NamedContextFactory.java:116) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getContext(NamedContextFactory.java:85) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getInstance(NamedContextFactory.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientFactoryBean.get(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:127) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientFactoryBean.feign(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:84) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getObject(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:155) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [feign.Retryer]: Factory method 'feignRetryer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NEVER_RETRY
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NEVER_RETRY
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsConfiguration.feignRetryer(FeignClientsConfiguration.java:110) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
...
```

The project is published in github: https://github.com/diogoaltoe/spring-cloud-microservices

The service that is experiencing the problem is the: server-gateway

It looks like the error is related to the client package files, for example:

- CustomerClient.java (https://github.com/diogoaltoe/spring-cloud-microservices/blob/master/server-gateway/src/main/java/com/diogoaltoe/microservices/client/CustomerController.java)
- CustomerController.java (https://github.com/diogoaltoe/spring-cloud-microservices/blob/master/server-gateway/src/main/java/com/diogoaltoe/microservices/client/CustomerController.java)

I am at least 2 days researching and testing various possibilities, but without success so far.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded all services to the Finchley version and now the gateway service works fine!
Thanks Spencer Gibb for the help!!!

**PS.1:** The discovery service using the Finchley version gave an error when registering in eureka and registering other services. As a solution I used the Edgware.SR4 version, which worked correctly.
**PS.2:** With the upgrade in gateway service, the authentication has stopped working and for now, I can only use it without authentication. I am researching to find out what has changed in the new version of Spring Cloud Security to fit my code.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, and later found that the release did not reference feign-core, when I added a reference to feign-core in the pom file, it will run normally.

add a reference to feign-core in the pom file：

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.feign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-core</artifactId>
            <version>${feign-version}</version>
</dependency>
```